# error in Ruby on Rails 6 app after deploying to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I have successfully deployed my ruby on rails app to Heroku - it currently has 3.1.2 ruby version. I can see the homepage in Heroku but when I go to log in as current user it says there is a problem with the app. I use gem Devise for this. This is what my heroku logs comes with: has this got to do with puma's version when trying to log-in as user?

```
2023-01-28T12:29:28.090153+00:00 app[web.1]: [31fa87ec-45d2-4d36-9d98-ce18f17a9fd7] rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
2023-01-28T12:29:28.090156+00:00 app[web.1]: [31fa87ec-45d2-4d36-9d98-ce18f17a9fd7] actionpack (6.1.4.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:113:in `call'
2023-01-28T12:29:28.090157+00:00 app[web.1]: [31fa87ec-45d2-4d36-9d98-ce18f17a9fd7] railties (6.1.4.4) lib/rails/engine.rb:539:in `call'
2023-01-28T12:29:28.090157+00:00 app[web.1]: [31fa87ec-45d2-4d36-9d98-ce18f17a9fd7] puma (5.6.1) lib/puma/configuration.rb:252:in `call'
2023-01-28T12:29:28.090157+00:00 app[web.1]: [31fa87ec-45d2-4d36-9d98-ce18f17a9fd7] puma (5.6.1) lib/puma/request.rb:77:in `block in handle_request'
2023-01-28T12:29:28.090158+00:00 app[web.1]: [31fa87ec-45d2-4d36-9d98-ce18f17a9fd7] puma (5.6.1) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:340:in `with_force_shutdown'
2023-01-28T12:29:28.090158+00:00 app[web.1]: [31fa87ec-45d2-4d36-9d98-ce18f17a9fd7] puma (5.6.1) lib/puma/request.rb:76:in `handle_request'
2023-01-28T12:29:28.090158+00:00 app[web.1]: [31fa87ec-45d2-4d36-9d98-ce18f17a9fd7] puma (5.6.1) lib/puma/server.rb:441:in `process_client'
2023-01-28T12:29:28.090159+00:00 app[web.1]: [31fa87ec-45d2-4d36-9d98-ce18f17a9fd7] puma (5.6.1) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:147:in `block in spawn_thread'
2023-01-28T12:29:28.091751+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/users/sign_in" host=driven.herokuapp.com request_id=31fa87ec-45d2-4d36-9d98-ce18f17a9fd7 fwd="37.222.199.40" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1755ms status=500 bytes=1827 protocol=https
```

do I need to upgrade puma's version? I can see in my Gemfile.lock both puma (5.6.1) and  puma (~> 5.0), or is it a question of upgrading to Rails 7?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Would you mind sharing the full error message, including the stacktrace? It feels like there are at least one or two line missing at the top that would tell the exact error type that was raised.

Comment: hey spickermann, I have run heroku logs -n 200 but it's far too long to paste it here, is there a way I can attach it?

Answer (score 0):

Same error happens to me but I just ran this command in heroku cli - run rake db:migrate and got fixed

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).